# Как получить текущие координаты?

Tags: android

Как получить текущие координаты только один раз?

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates();
```

Это не то. Так как она создает таймер и по таймеру отдает координаты. А таймер я использую свой. И получаю координаты, то есть мне нужно, получить текущие координаты 1 раз и закрыть поток получения координат... Можно ли такое сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getLastKnownLocation может вернуть старые данные или вообще их не вернуть, если местоположение не определялось ранее.

Он не запрашивает местоположение заново.

Он "паразитирует" на данных запрошенных другими приложениями.

Для разового запроса координат надо использовать:

```
public void requestSingleUpdate (String provider, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)
```

как листенер отработает, можешь закрывать поток в котором запросил координаты.

Answer (score 0):

Если бы немного больше бы уделили бы время прочтению доков, то увидели бы, что у `LocationManager` есть ещё такой чудесный метод, как [getLastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String))
Вот он и позволяет получить самые свежие координаты